# Trying to find the Solaris/Unix Veritas VCS Single Cluster Manager (Java Console)

Tags: gui, cluster, version-control

I have an old install of VCSHA installed on my Sparc kit (Solaris 11 with VCS V5), and would like to try and get the  VCS Single Cluster Manager (Java Console) installed.
When i attempt to run it, i get a message that states its no longer packaged with the installer.

```
Symantec recommends use of the Veritas Cluster Server Management Console to manage, monitor 
and report on multi-cluster environments. You can download this utility at 
no charge at http://go.symantec.com/vcsmc.
```

Unfortunately since symantec has been bought out, the page no longer exists and i cannot find the installer package on the broadcom site.

I am hoping that someone on here can either provide or point me to the package.

Comment: This link?  
https://www.veritas.com/form/trialware/vcs-utilities